# An odd and random partition I found on an older HDD that I've put back into use

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, toshiba-hard-drive

I recently added an HDD to my computer so I could enjoy more storage. I was and am running Windows 10 on an SSD, my C drive. As expected, the HDD shows up as D: drive. However, on the drive there is a E: partition. In the disk management program, I don't have the ability to format it or anything else. All it shows for actions when clicking on it is "Help". Additional information; Nothing important is currently stored on it. It's a Toshiba drive I extracted from a no longer in use HP laptop, about 5-10 years old. E: and all other partitions/drives are NTFS. Disk managements labels all my drives/partitions as Healthy. It's also labeled as a Basic Data Partition. The HDD is a terabyte, D: is 903.55 GBs and E: is 25.97 GBs. In the file explorer with the "Hidden Files" setting on the drive doesn't appear to be storing anything, though in CMD by `cd`ing into the partition and running `dir /a:h` it lists the following(I'm cutting out likely arbitrary info):

```
 Directory of E:\

<DIR>          $RECYCLE.BIN
<DIR>          Boot
       427,680 bootmgr
     1,612,128 bootmgr.efi
<DIR>          EFI
<DIR>          preload
            55 RP.ini
<DIR>          sources
<DIR>          System Volume Information
               3 File(s)      2,039,863 bytes
               6 Dir(s)   3,048,054,784 bytes free
```

**Key questions: Why is this partition here(My best guest is it has to do with it's use in the old laptop)? Is safe for me to remove the partition? If it is safe for me to do so then how do I remove it?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided that you are not booting off this drive it is safe to remove it.   This partition is used for (U)EFI booting so is only relevant to the boot process of a machine programmed to use it.